# GetElementsByTagName in C#

Tags: c#, browser

I have this piece of code:

```
string x = textBox1.Text;
string[] list = x.Split(';');
foreach (string u in list)
{
    string url = "http://*********/index.php?n=" + u;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("META");
}
```

and I'm trying to get the `<META>` tags to output to a message box, but when I test it out, I keep getting this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: If all you need is to get some meta tags, why are you instantiating an entire web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're accessing the `Document` object before the document has loaded - `WebBrowser`s are asynchronous. Just parse the HTML using a library like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Here's how you might get the `<meta>` tags using the HTML Agility Pack. (Assumes `using System.Net;` and `using HtmlAgilityPack;`.)

```
// Create a WebClient to use to download the string:
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    // Create a document object
    HtmlDocument d = new HtmlDocument();

    // Download the content and parse the HTML:        
    d.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368605/getelementsbytagname-in-c-sharp/10368631#10368631"));

    // Loop through all the <meta> tags:
    foreach(HtmlNode metaTag in d.DocumentNode.Descendants("meta")) {
        // It's a <meta> tag! Do something with it.
    }
}
```

Comment: okay so i did this but i still cant get it to echo correctly...i did

  foreach(HtmlNode metaTag in d.DocumentNode.Descendants("meta")) {
        MessageBox(metaTag.ToString());
    }

Comment: @user1363561: Use `metaTag.OuterHtml`, not `metaTag.ToString()`.

Comment: this helps me a lot but now it just shows "<meta>" i need it to grab the content inbetween <meta>

<meta>12994</meta> 12994 is what i need to grab...sorry for the trouble

Comment: @user1363561: There's not supposed to be anything between `<meta>` tags - only in its attributes. Is this your website? If so, you'll want to change it. Otherwise, regular expressions are an option, or you could just grab the next node using `metaTag.NextSibling`.

Comment: okay, well in that case ill change it to <div> tags but i still need the content inbetween the div tags <div>12994</div> i need to be able to grab the 12994

Comment: @user1363561: Then use `InnerText` or `InnerHtml` instead of `OuterHtml`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to access the document until it has finish loading. Run that code inside a handler for the [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event.

But Matti is right. If all you need is to read the HTML you shouldn't be using a `WebBrowser`. Just fetch the text and parse it using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve META tags and any other HTML element directly from your WebBrowser control, there is no need of HTML Agility Pack or other component.

Like Mark said, wait first for the DocumentCompleted event:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
```

Then you can catch any element and content from the HTML document. The following code gets the title and the meta description:

```
private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = sender as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;
        string title = browser.Document.Title;
        string description = String.Empty;
        foreach (HtmlElement meta in browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("META"))
        {
            if (meta.Name.ToLower() == "description")
            {
                description = meta.GetAttribute("content");
            }
        }
}
```