# .net equivalent to MSHTML Object Library?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Right now, I am using MSHTML to extract data from NAME/ID tags through AX web browser control, and it works well for its intended purpose.  I know that the .NET browser is supposed to be the way to go, but I cant find where it will allow me to search for an element by name like so:

```
.getelementsbyname("ELEMENTNAME").item(#)
```

Not all the fields I pull have ID tags, and not all of them have any tags other than html table tags.  I'm simply wondering if there is a .net reference similar to MSHTML that is compatible with the .net browser?  As well, what advantages exist for using the .net browser? Or does this sort of thing end up being personal preference? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetElementsByTagName in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368605/getelementsbytagname-in-c-sharp)

Comment: definitely not a duplicate of that thread.  I am seeking a way in .net to do what the COM object MSHTML handles, natively.  Im guessing there is no way? @Neolisk thanks for the link, but I was wondering if a reference to a non-com version for parsing  theweb browser controlexists natively in vb.net

Comment: @JasonBayldon: I never worked with MSHTML object library, so not sure what exactly you need here. If you provide more detail, we can hopefully better understand your needs.

Comment: @Neolisk I am looking for a way to pull elements from a web page using the .net web browser control.  The native control lets you pull from a web field via ID by declaring `Dim htmldocument As HtmlDocument` then `htmldocument.getelementbyID("NAME")`, but not all my fields have relative ID's, some have a name only and I need to use `.getelementbynames("ITEMNAME").ITEM(INDEX#)`.  I figured there was a way to do this somehow using .net and not COM.

Comment: @JasonBayldon: Did you look into Html Agility Pack? Point is you don't need a browser control to be able to pull elements from a web page. Even if you do need a browser control for something else, you can pull its HTML property (or whatever) and feed that into this agility pack. I never used it myself, but it's been suggested here many times, so it must be good enough to try.

Comment: @Neolisk Thanks for the advice, I am definitely checking it out and seeing where it takes me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)? You don't need a browser control to be able to pull elements from a web page. Even if you do need a browser control for other purposes, you can pull its HTML property (or whatever) and feed that into this agility pack. I never used it myself, but it's been suggested here many times, so it must be good enough to try.